# Apply expression to synchronize multiple map extents in QGIS 3 layout using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I am using the following code to make a map with multiple map items. I would like to add the synchronization of the maps extents.

How do you apply an expression to the min/max extents of a map item on a layout using PyQGIS 3?

```
selectedLayers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

mapCanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
mapThemesCollection = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
mapThemes = mapThemesCollection.mapThemes()
    
mapRowCount = 2
mapColCount = 6

lrMargins = [10,10]   #set Left/Right Margins
tbMargins = [20,30]   #set Top/Bottom Margins

"""Create a new print layout"""
layoutName = "Multi Map {}x{}".format(mapRowCount,mapColCount)

project = QgsProject.instance() 
manager = project.layoutManager() 
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)  
layout.initializeDefaults()  
layout.setName(layoutName)
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.pages()[0].setPageSize('A3', QgsLayoutItemPage.Landscape)
manager.addLayout(layout)

iMapCanvas =0
mapOriginYMm = tbMargins[0]   
mapOriginXMm = lrMargins[0]   

for iRow in range(1,mapRowCount+1):
    for iCol in  range(1,mapColCount +1):
        #Remember 0,0 is Top Left..... TL to LR
        try:
            layer = selectedLayers[iMapCanvas]
            item_id = "{} - {}".format(iMapCanvas,layer.name())
            title = layer.name()

        except:
            layer=None
            item_id = str(iMapCanvas)
            title = 'Map {}'.format(iMapCanvas)
            

        map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
        map.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)
        
        map.setExtent(mapCanvas.extent())
        map.setBackgroundEnabled(False)
        map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(mapOriginXMm,mapOriginYMm,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
        map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(fraWidth,fraHeight,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
        map.setId('Map {}'.format(item_id))
        layout.addLayoutItem(map)

        if iMapCanvas == 0:
            exp_ymin = QgsExpression("y_min(map_get( item_variables( {} ), 'map_extent'))".format( map.id()))
            exp_ymax = QgsExpression("y_max(map_get( item_variables( {} ), 'map_extent'))".format( map.id()))
            exp_xmin = QgsExpression("x_min(map_get( item_variables(  {} ), 'map_extent'))".format( map.id()))
            exp_xmax = QgsExpression("x_maxn(map_get( item_variables(  {} ), 'map_extent'))".format( map.id()))
        else:
            # How do I apply the expressions to the map item 
            pass
        
        # add Title
        map_title ="Title - Map {}".format(iMapCanvas)
        
        if layer is not None: 
            map_title = layer.name()
            if layer.name() in mapThemes:
                map.setFollowVisibilityPreset(True)
                map.setFollowVisibilityPresetName(layer.name())
                
        title = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
        title.setText(map_title)
        title.setFont(QFont('Arial', 14,QFont.Bold))
        title.setId("Title - Map {}".format(iMapCanvas))
        title.adjustSizeToText()
        layout.addLayoutItem(title)
        title.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(mapOriginXMm, mapOriginYMm, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    
        mapOriginXMm += fraWidth
        iMapCanvas += 1

    mapOriginYMm += fraHeight     # Add next row
    mapOriginXMm = lrMargins[0]              # reset to left edge of page
    
# open the layout
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a data defined property.

```
map.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsLayoutObject.MapXMin, QgsProperty.fromExpression(exp_xmin))
map.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsLayoutObject.MapYMin, QgsProperty.fromExpression(exp_ymin))
map.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsLayoutObject.MapXMax, QgsProperty.fromExpression(exp_xmax))
map.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsLayoutObject.MapYMax, QgsProperty.fromExpression(exp_ymax))
```